# Legality of Cyber Attack on illegal foreign website

Tags: internet, international, hacking

I live in a country where website that provides pornography, illegal drugs, prostitution, illegal gambling, etc are forbidden (in Indonesia). But foreign websites (ex. from western countries) on those service are just insisting to provide access to my country despite the govt in my country already tries to block it all. Is it legal to attack those websites by our personal cyber force in order to shut them down? it will help the govt and useful for training

Answer (score 4):

It is probably illegal under Indonesian law for you to launch a cyber-attack on a website that you believe violates Indonesian law, just as it is illegal for you to shoot a person for fraud. The Indonesian government reserves the right to judge guilt or innocence, and to mete out punishment, within Indonesia. It is definitely illegal under US law, also UK law and so on, to launch a cyber-attack on a website for some reason, so you can be prosecuted under the laws of that nation. You should then be concerned with the [Law on Extradition (1979)](https://www.imolin.org/doc/amlid/Indonesia_Law%20on%20Extradition.pdf), noting that there might be a treaty but also Indonesian law allows extradition on the basis of the  interest  of  Indonesia (as judged by government officials). Indonesian nationals do not enjoy immunity from extradition (as is the case in some countries). There is no extradition treaty between Indonesia and the US; there was one between the UK and Indonesia but I cannot determine whether it is still in force.